# Exception on threaded code

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

```
    import thread
    import time

    #Define a function for the thread
    def Print_Time(threadname,delay):
        count = 0
        while count < 5:
            time.sleep(delay)
            count += 1
            print "%s %s" %(threadname,time.ctime( time.time() ))

    #create two threads
    try:
        thread.start_new_thread(Print_Time("Thread1",2))
        thread.start_new_thread(Print_Time("Thread2",4))
    except:
        print "Error: unable to start thread"
```

When I run this code, thread one is spawned and printed five times in the output.The moment thread two is to be spawned and exception happens.

Please help to resolve this exception. Thanks in advance.

Comment: !. Format your code 2. Post the exception that you get. 3. Post a complete example that other people can just copy/paste and run themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use `try-except` and discard the exception which gives you more information what happened? Your own error message `Error: unable to start thread` will obviously not give you enough information what happened.

```
try:
    pass # ...
except Exception, e:
    print(e) # start_new_thread expected at least 2 arguments, got 1
```

When you avoid `try` or print out the exception you see that something is wrong with the way how you passed the arguments to `start_new_thread`. From the documentation you can see how the parameters are passed.

> thread.start_new_thread(function, args[, kwargs])

```
# False - you execute Print_time on your own
# and pass the return value to start_new_thread
thread.start_new_thread(Print_time("Thread1",2))

# Correct
thread.start_new_thread(Print_time, ("Thread1",2))
thread.start_new_thread(Print_time, ("Thread2",4))
```

Keep in mind that your main thread will be finished before your threads will be finished. Wait for them with a timer or better use [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)
 which helps you to wait on the threads you started.

Comment: I avoided the try  and got this error   File "static_method.py", line 14, in <module>
    thread.start_new_thread(Print_time("Thread1",2))
TypeError: start_new_thread expected at least 2 arguments, got 1

Comment: So, to avoid this error....and let the second thread in my code to be spawned...what should be done by me as I am new to python ? @HelloWorld

Comment: Please read my answer again. I wrote the counterpart how you use that correctly.

Comment: Thanks...for the solution.